# How are methods linked to components?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm doing a tutorial and I'm confused as to how Angular2 knows what method to call in what component.  Here is an example...

The following is in the `recipe-list.component.html`:

```
  <div class="col-xs-12">
  <ul class="list-group">
      <rb-recipe-item [recipe] = "recipe"  (click) = "onSelected(recipe)"></rb-recipe-item>
  </ul>
```

I understand that the property `[recipe]` is part of the `rb-recipe-item` component.

The `(click)` calls the `onSelected` method that is in the `recipe-list.component.ts`. But how does Angular2 know this method is located in `recipe-list.component.ts`?

If I wanted to call a method located in the `rb-recipe-item` component (or any other component), how would I do that?

Comment: It knows because that's the component whose markup you're defining the binding in. If you want to use a method in the child component, bind the event on the outermost element in the child markup. If you want to use a method somewhere else, you'll have to explicitly orchestrate that via a common parent component.

Comment: But I'm binding the [recipe] property in the same markup.  Does it relate that property to the "rb-recipe-item" Component simply because I'm using the brackets [ ] ?

Comment: Brackets `[]` and parentheses `()` mean inward and outward bindings respectively. The `click` event is coming out of the child component and you're binding it to the method on the current component. The `recipe` is being fed (sorry) into the child component from the current component.

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  Your description helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A Component is related to a template or a template url(if you write HTML in a separate file).
Template or template url(do not use both in the same Component), are defined in the Component metadata.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-selector',
    template: // your template here
    //Which is calling the recipe
})
export class YourComponent{
   recipe(){
   // body of the method recipe
   }
}
```